# Criar um usuário sem Logout do atual - Firebase

Tags: angular, ionic, firebase

Quando estou logado no App e crio um novo usuário automaticamente o usuário ativo passa a ser esse recém criado.
Alguma solução com AngularFire pra contornar isso?

colaborador.ts

```
  colaborador: Colaborador = new Colaborador();
  @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  addColaborador(colaborador: Colaborador){
    if (this.form.form.valid) {
         this.authService.createColaborador(colaborador)
          .then((colaborador: any) => {
            colaborador.sendEmailVerification();
            this.alertToast('Colaborador incluído com sucesso.');
          })
          .catch((error: any) => {
            if (error.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
              this.alertToast('O e-mail utilizado já está em uso.');
            } else if (error.code == 'auth/invalid-email') {
              this.alertToast('O e-mail digitado não é valido.');
            } else if (error.code == 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
              this.alertToast('Usuário não autorizado a criar contas.');
            }
          });
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user/38013551#38013551

Comment: @EduardoVargas, já tinha visto mas não esclarece. Acredito que a questão que vc colocou se desenrola em um back-end separado da aplicação.

Comment: Paece que tem 3 soluções criar uma conexão secundaria com o fiirebase, fazer pelo backend com vc chamando o back e o back chamando o firebase ou então comando o firebase por um post inves de usar esse wrapper deles.